# How to remove zeros after a comma or dot from price (currency)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Am trying to remove trailing zeros after `,` or `.` in a currency, still retaining the currency sign. For example, `€90.00` to `€90`, `90.00€` to `90€` and `€90.33` to `€90.33`.

The example can be found below:

```js
$('.product-price-wrapp').each(function() { 
    var productPrice = $(this).find('.price').text();
    var trimPrice = productPrice.substr(0,productPrice.indexOf(',')); 
  productPrice.text(trimPrice);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #20262E;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.price {
  color: green;
}

.price span {
  color: #747474;
} 

.price:first-child,
.price:last-child,
.price:nth-of-type(6){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-price-wrapp">
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> 90,00 €</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> 90,30 €</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> 90,45 €</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> 92,67 €</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> 33.33 €</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> £22.00</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> £72,22</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> £72,00</div>
</div>
```

WORKING VERSION: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JNfrontend/qvn857ye/88/)

You are all amazing, thanks a lot to you all for your help!
Credit: @Cocest @A. Ramos @Ivan

Comment: Edit your question so that I will post the answer to your problem

Comment: Hi Cocest, I did try to edit the question but its still [on hold] by Robert Harvey.

Should I create a new question?

Comment: I have edited the question for you. Review it. Thank you.

Comment: Try to explain what the code sample does

Comment: Thank you so much for this Cocest.

Comment: So in the code sample, I did try to do a loop that checked every price witch class ".price" and if there is 00 after , or . it will replace to price without zeros

For example, €90.00 to €90, 90.00€ to 90€ and €90.33 to €90.33

Comment: I don't think the sample code is necessary. Maybe, you should remove it

Comment: I removed the code, I think should be ok now?

Comment: @Cocest, it's better to keep the code, it shows that he tried solving the problem. You should put the code back in the original post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to add another container for the price per se if you need to retain the color of the text because you're trying to change the text content of the ".price"

your code will look like this:

```html
<div class="product-price-wrapp">
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> <span class="price_tag">90,00 €</span></div>
  ...
</div>
```

then use the regex pattern `/(\d+)([.,]0+)/` to remove the zeroes.

```
$('.product-price-wrapp .price .price_tag').each(function(){
   var price = $(this).text();
   price = price.replace(/(\d+)([.,]0+)/, "$1");
   $(this).text(price);
});
```

for the regex pattern, it has two capturing groups.

$1 = **(\d+)** : gets all one number or more.
$2 = **([.,]0+)** : gets all the trailing zero with dot or comma on its first character.

so, when we used it on the code, we are all replacing the content that matches the pattern [number (1 or more)][comma or dot followed by trailing zeroes], then retain only the first capturing group which is the number (one or more).

Comment: Your solution failed to pass these samples: `€20.02` and `20.02€`

Comment: Hi @Cocest I presume, you used my javascript code, without changing the HTML code. I think this is the reason why on your end, it failed.

PS. He/She used my solution on his/her [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JNfrontend/qvn857ye/88/) and it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ivan, you could check this [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JNfrontend/qvn857ye/88/). I think, you forgot to change your html code too. Thanks!

Comment: I already went to this link, the point is: if you use `92,07 €` for example, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression in order to detect if the price contains a trailing comma: either `,00` or `.00`, if so you can replace it with an empty string.

I have used this regular expression:

```
/[\.,]0{2}/
```

- `[\.,]` searches for either `.` or `,`
- `0{2}` followed by two zeros

Here's the full code.

```js
$('.product-price-wrapp > .price').each(function(index, element) {
  
  var priceElement = $(element);
  
  priceElement.text(
    'Product Price ' + priceElement.text().substring(14).replace(/[\.,]0{2}/, '')
  );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-price-wrapp">
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> 90,00 €</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> 90,30 €</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> 90,45 €</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> 92,67 €</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> 33.33 €</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> £22.00</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> £72,22</div>
  <br>
  <div class="price"><span>Product Price</span> £72,00</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution. It's more flexible, it works for any price.

```
var c = '90,00 €'; //assign currency (value)

c = /[.,]0*[1-9]+/.test(c) ? c : c.replace(/[.,]0+/, '');

// use the currency here
```